# Pandas: Find most common string per person

Tags: python, pandas

I would like find the most common string value in `animal` when aggregating data by `id`, if the count is the same, I would like to pick the last value of `animal`.

```
   id   animal       date
0   1    dog      2018-01-01
1   1    dog      2018-01-02
2   1    cat      2018-01-03
3   2    cat      2018-01-01
4   3    dog      2018-01-01
5   4   fish      2018-01-01
6   5    dog      2018-01-01
7   5    cat      2018-01-02
```

The output should look something like:

```
   id animal
0  1   dog
1  2   cat
2  3   dog
3  4   fish
4  5   cat
```

I haven't been able to get this to work properly. I tried using `pd.get_dummies` and counting but not look. Ideally, the solution will use in build, vectorised pandas/numpy, i.e. filtering, join, np.where, etc as `groupby.apply`is very slow and data is somewhat sizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

group by `id` & `animal` columns and get the `count` and `last` date on which they appeared.

then sort the resulting data frame by `id`, `count`, `last` and drop duplicate values on `id`, keeping the last row, which due to our ordering, will give the most common animal, and if there are two animals, the animal that was last observed in the table. finally, get rid of the extra columns `count` & `last`

```
columns = ['id', 'animal']

df2 = df.groupby(columns).date.agg(['count', 'last']).reset_index()
df3 = df2.sort_values(['id', 'count', 'last'])
df3.drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')[columns]

# outputs:

   id animal
1   1    dog
2   2    cat
3   3    dog
4   4   fish
5   5    cat
```

Comment: This is the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom rule and `aggregate` using it

```
from collections import Counter
def rule(a):
    m = Counter(a)
    max_val = sorted(m.values())[-1]
    return max(a) if m.values().count(max_val) == 1 else a.tail(1).item()

df.groupby("id").aggregate(rule)
```

---

Output:

```
   animal
id  
1   dog
2   cat
3   dog
4   fish
5   cat
```