# Find the most common cell in a dataframe per group of another common

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, frequency

I have a dataset with a column `id` and a column `lang`.

```
>>> all_transcripts

id  lang
1   nl   
1   nl
1   fr
1   nl
2   en
2   nl
2   en
3   nl
3   nl
```

Now I want to create a column `actual_lang` that shows the most common `lang` per `interactionId`. My desired output looks as follows:

```
id  lang    actual_lang
1   nl      nl
1   nl      nl
1   fr      nl
1   nl      nl
2   en      en
2   nl      en
2   en      en
3   nl      nl
3   nl      nl
```

I have found [Pandas: Find most common string per person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49821754/pandas-find-most-common-string-per-person), however here the returned value is based on two columns and the output comes per single group item, rather than added on to the dataset.

Who knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) and selecting first value:

```
df['actual_lang'] = df.groupby('id')['lang'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
print (df)
   id lang actual_lang
0   1   nl          nl
1   1   nl          nl
2   1   fr          nl
3   1   nl          nl
4   2   en          en
5   2   nl          en
6   2   en          en
7   3   nl          nl
8   3   nl          nl
```

Comment: This code works on a test dataset with only 10 000 rows. However, on my actual dataset, it does not work and I get the error: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2556944 elements, new values have 2574855 elements` I've checked for empty values and for non-alpha values, but each cell is filled. Do you know how this is possible?

Comment: @Emil - I s possible missing values in `id` column?